# Submit multiple forms using only 1 ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm getting my multiple forms using a `while` loop (fetch data in the database).

```
<form id="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" >
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="test1">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="car_type">
<button type="submit" class="buttona" id="buttona">Send</button>
</form>
<form id="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" >
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="test2">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="car_type" value="test2">
<button type="submit" class="buttona" id="buttona">Send</button>
</form>
```

Here's my ajax (It only works in the 1st form but the rest not working):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $(".form").submit(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        $("#buttona").html('...');
        $("#buttona").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        sendInfo();

     });
});
```

Function for ajax:

```
function sendInfo() { 
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '../process.php',
          data: $(".form").serialize(),
          success: function(data){
             if(data == 'Success') {
                $('#text_errora').html('added');
             }else {
               $('#text_errora').html('not aadded');                    
               }
          }
      })
        return false;
    }
```

How can I set or how ajax will recognize the button I click/submit to process the form?

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't close your `<form>` tag.
2. You use the same `id` twice.
3. You select anything with class `form`, not ID `form`.

Actually, I am amazed it works even one time.

Try this (no need to touch the JavaScript), your form should submit, but the button changing might not work (you use identical IDs there too; tip: an `id` has to be unique within the *entire* HTML DOM).

```
<form class="form form-horizontal" method="post" >
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="test1">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="car_type">
<button type="submit" class="buttona" id="buttona">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi bro I checked it has a close tag. I also changed the ID (using $i++). but how can I call the ID form in ajax?

Comment: Show the *actual* code please, we might be able to help better. (And I am not your bro.)

Comment: I echo all the value inside the form then use 1 ajax only the edit/send the data again.

Answer (score 0):

Using "**this**" keyword inside submit handler, you will receive a reference to the form to which the clicked button belongs.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(".form").submit(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        var form_to_submit = this;
        $("#buttona").html('...');
        $("#buttona").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        sendInfo(form_to_submit);

     });
});


function sendInfo(form_to_submit) { 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../process.php',
        data: $(form_to_submit).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if(data == 'Success') {
                $('#text_errora').html('added');
            }else {
                $('#text_errora').html('not aadded');                    
            }
        }
    })
    return false;
}
```